# VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER when setting apiVersion parameter to 0

Tags: c++, driver, vulkan

I am trying to create a vulkan instance. Here is my code:

```
vk::ApplicationInfo appInfo("Test", 1, nullptr, 0, 0);
vk::InstanceCreateInfo info;
info.pApplicationInfo(&appInfo);
vk::Instance instance;
const auto result = vk::createInstance(&info, nullptr, &instance);
std::cout << vkResultToString(result) << std::endl;
```

However this returns VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER.

If I don't provide my own `ApplicationInfo` and instead use a default constructed one, it works.

In the [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/pdf/vkspec.pdf) it says

> If `apiVersion` is 0 the implementation must ignore it, otherwise if the implementation does not support the requested `apiVersion` it must return `VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER`

As you can see I set `apiVersion` to 0. To my understanding it should not give me the `VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER` error then.

Is this a bug or am I forgetting something or thinking wrong?

**EDIT:**

In the html version of the [specification](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/v1/docs/v1.0.3.1/vulkandocs/vkspec.html#devsandqueues-initialization) the part about ignoring `apiVersion` isn't there. Is the pdf version of the specification just outdated?

**EDIT:**

If I am setting `apiVersion` to 1.0.3 it also works:

```
std::bitset<32> apiVersion;
apiVersion.set(22);
apiVersion.set(1);
apiVersion.set(0);
vk::ApplicationInfo appInfo("Test", 1, nullptr, 0, apiVersion.to_ulong());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds entirely like a developmental option that was removed from the final spec.  If you consider how much any graphics API changes from one major version to another, it seems unsafe to allow such behavior as default.  That being said, it would be entirely up to the graphics driver manufacturer to support this as they are the ones with final say over whether or not something like this is accepted.

Additionally, if you look at the official API spec: https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/apispec.html.

That merely states: "Finally, apiVersion is the version of the Vulkan API that the application expects to use."

Comment: Your link (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/apispec.html) is not to the specification, it is to the reference documentation. The relevant bit of the specification is here: https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/xhtml/vkspec.html#VkApplicationInfo. Having said that you are a developer at LunarG so please clarify if I am wrong.

Comment: You are correct, that is the API "Reference" Spec. Still it and the Vulkan Language spec (as mentioned by yuumei below) should agree.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the html spec you are looking at is outdated:

> Revision 0.9 Provisional  Wed Nov 11 18:11:51 PST 2015

It has the quote about `apiVersion` here https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/pdf/vkspec.pdf and here https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/xhtml/vkspec.html These are version 1.0

As for the results, it may be a bug. What driver/platform are you using?

Comment: I am using the beta driver from NVIDIA for Windows 10.

Comment: This is explicitly a Beta driver so bugs are possible, although it has passed the 1.0 conformance tests.

Answer (score 1):

You ask the question:

> Is this a bug or am I forgetting something or thinking wrong?

Since the specification is canonical, yes it is a bug. [The specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/xhtml/vkspec.html#VkApplicationInfo) says these two relevant things:

> apiVersion is the version of the Vulkan API against which the application expects to run, encoded as described in the
>   API Version Numbers and Semantics section. If apiVersion is 0 the implementation must ignore it, otherwise if the
>   implementation does not support the requested apiVersion it must return VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER.
>
> apiVersion must be zero, or otherwise it must be a version that the implementation supports, or supports an effective substitute for

For now, you can keep doing what you are doing and request a version that is both `<=` the version in the SDK you are building against and `<=` the versions of the drivers you want to be able to run on.

Comment: This won't always work, for example the latest vulkan SDK now is 1.0.5, but drivers only support vulkan up 1.0.4. In this case you can use VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 4) instead of VK_API_VERSION.

Comment: @IceCool, Good point. I guess `VK_MAKE_VERSION(WHATEVER_VERSION_YOU_HAVE_ACTUALLY_TESTED_ON_OR_ARE_WILLING_TO_BET_YOUR_APP_CAN_RUN_ON_THAT_IS_LOWER_THAN_WHAT_YOU_HAVE_TRIED_IT_ON)` is the way to go. This is what is working for the OP anyway.